# What density bucket would a device with a PPI of 206 be in

Tags: android

I have looked through the documentation on multiple screen sizes but it was very confusing... 
here is what i understand:
if mdpi is 1, ldpi is 0.75 of that.
hdpi is 1.5 of that, and xhdpi is 2.0 of that

Comment: can you please also explain your reasoning ?

Comment: Did you mean 206 dpi?

Comment: You can't know in advance how Android determines your 206 dpi device. You can only check it: DisplayMetrics mMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mMetrics); float density = mMetrics.scaledDensity. If density = 1 your device is treated as mdpi, if density = 1.5 then it's hdpi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

206 DPI will more than likely be tvdpi.  you can view a list of all [densities here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

This will tell you your devices multiplier (ie: 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2..):

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```